# why there is a big different time consuming when canvas function getImageData excute in different situation

Tags: javascript, performance, canvas

Check this [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/c5qk8b2d/),

the only difference is a stroke rect is drawn in the left canvas before click, and rect is drawn in the right canvas when click.

```
function getPointColor(ctx, x, y) {
    return ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
}


function getTime(ctx, action) {
    console.time(action);
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        getPointColor(ctx, 1, 1);
    }
    console.timeEnd(action);
}
ctx1.strokeRect(0, 0, 20, 20)

canvas1.onclick = function () {
    getTime(ctx1, 'click canvas1');
}

canvas2.onclick = function () {
    ctx2.strokeRect(0, 0, 20, 20)
    getTime(ctx2, 'click canvas2');
}
```

And the console is shown time consuming of canvas1 is 100 times than canvas2;

[image]

Comment: What does `getTime` do? Please include all the relevant code in your question, not just in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's [a Chrome bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001845) that started from roughly v76.
This is linked to Hardware Acceleration, disabling it will make both operations take the same minimal time.

Note though that current Canary version (v78) has a different behavior now (probably because of [this commit](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0e20fdf5f2660a7ee2ea0dd540070dbe2ce08b40)), where both operations will take the maximal time...

I already opened the linked bug report, so there is not much more to do, except if you're able to propose a fix there.

---

The issue is that they now keep the canvas buffer in the GPU memory most of the time, but in order to get the ImageData, they need to transfer it back to the CPU. Thus calling this method multiple times like you do will require them to perform this transfer as many times.

So a simple fix for you, which you should use anyway the bug is fixed or not, is to rewrite your `getPointColor` in a way it performs `getImageData` only once.

Instead of calling `getImageData(x, y, 1, 1)` several times to get different points, you should get only one ImageData representing all the canvas and then picking the pixel's value from this big ImageData:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// gets the slot at x y coords from a flatten pixel matrix represented as 32bits
function getPixelColor32(data, x, y, width) {
  return data[y * width + x];
}
// set the value of the slots at x, y (32bits version)
function setPixelColor32(val, data, x, y, width) {
  data[y * width + x] = val;
}
// the same functions
// in case you wish to keep the orignal Uint8ClampedArray from ImageData
// returns a new Uint8ClampedArray, not that good for memory
function getPixelColor8(data, x, y, width) {
  const index = (y * width + x) * 4;
  return data.slice(index, index + 4);
}
// here vals is an Array like object of length 4 [r, g, b, a]
function setPixelColor8(vals, data, x, y, width) {
  const index = (y * width + x) * 4;
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i ++) {
    data[index + i] = vals[i];
  }
}

// so we can draw a circle
function distanceFromCenter(x, y, cx, cy) {
  return Math.hypot(cx - x, cy - y);
}

let mouse_down = false;
canvas.onmousedown = (evt) => {
  mouse_down = true;
  draw(evt);
};
canvas.onmousemove = (evt) => {
  if(mouse_down) {
    draw(evt);
  }
};
canvas.onmouseup = (evt) => {
  mouse_down = false;
}
function draw(evt) {
  const { width, height } = canvas;
  const rad = height / 10;
  const cx = evt.offsetX;
  const cy = evt.offsetY;

  // we call getImageData only once
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);
  // using an Uint32Array view for easier pixel manipulation
  // we could obviously also use the Uint8Clamped version,
  // though it would use more memory
  const data = new Uint32Array(imgData.data.buffer);

  for( let x = 0; x < width; x ++) {
    for( let y = 0; y < height; y ++) {
      // make a circle
      if(distanceFromCenter(x, y, cx, cy) < rad + 1) {
        // get the pixel value (here as 32bit)
        const px = getPixelColor32(data, x, y, width);
        // do something with it (negative)
        setPixelColor32(~px | 0xFF000000, data, x, y, width);
      }
    }
  }
  ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
};

// just to draw something at beginning
const px_size = 10;
const noise = new ImageData(canvas.width / px_size, canvas.height / px_size);
new Uint32Array(noise.data.buffer)
  .forEach((v, i, a) => {
    a[i] = Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF + 0xFF000000;
  });
ctx.putImageData(noise, 0 ,0);
ctx.scale(px_size, px_size);
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
```

```html
<pre>click &amp; drag to do pixel manip</pre>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

#### Update:

Since this answer has been posted, and the bugs open, Chrome has implemented a new `willReadFrequently` context setting, that was already available in Firefox and [made it to the specs](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/6764).

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {willReadFrequently: true});
```

This option is an hint to the browser that your code will make many read-backs and that it should thus optimize the context for this use. Concretely, in Chrome, this will prevent hardware acceleration.
So this option may be a good solution for the ones that absolutely need to do many read-backs during their app's life, but beware this also comes with the penalty of losing hardware acceleration altogether.

Answer (score 0):

1. 写操作后，同步执行读操作：https://jsfiddle.net/np381yfd/

```
ctx1.strokeRect(0, 0, 20, 20);
ctx1.getImageData(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

2. 根据楼上回复推测：[diff](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/0e20fdf5f2660a7ee2ea0dd540070dbe2ce08b40%5E%21/#F3)

```
index 1c2001a..204b16d 100644
--- a/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/graphics/canvas_2d_layer_bridge.cc
+++ b/third_party/blink/renderer/platform/graphics/canvas_2d_layer_bridge.cc
@@ -141,6 +141,8 @@
     accelerate = true;
   } else if (acceleration_mode_ == kDisableAcceleration) {
     accelerate = false;
+  } else if (acceleration_mode_ == kEnableAcceleration) {
+    accelerate = true;
   } else {
     accelerate = hint == kPreferAcceleration ||
                  hint == kPreferAccelerationAfterVisibilityChange;
```

3. 进一步分析：16GB源码clone中……